Como evaluar una "cadena" vacía que realmente no está vacía? (TinyMCE)
Recuerdan el post que hice sobre los saltos de línea hace unos días??
Bien, con ese mismo textarea tengo un "problema", y es que me está aceptando "cadenas vacías", y ahora les explico porqué lo pongo entre comillas.
Si en el textarea que uso con TinyMCE en lugar de un texto hago 3 veces "enter", el texto que se guarda en la DB es <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
Obviamente, cuando evalúo con PHP que la cadena no esté vacía, me dice que no es cierto porque lleva tags html en ella.
$content = trim($_POST['content']);
// o usando
$content = (empty(trim($_POST['content']))) ? NULL : trim($_POST['content']);

// Si yo hago un control (esto es para ver que no vaya vacío el contenido)
if (strlen($content) === 0){ 
// o usando
if (empty($content)){ 
    $out[] = '<br>El contenido no puede quedar Vacío !!!';
    $class = 'danger';
    include_once 'alert.php';
}
else{
    echo $content;
    // Acá retorna en el navegador 3 "enters" (o sea 3 párrafos vacíos)
}

El resultado en pantalla es






Es decir, lo que representan 3 enters o 3 saltos de linea, o párrafos, como sea que les quieran llamar. Obviamente ese "código html" pasa a la base como (<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>) y en la descripción del usuario no se ve nada, es como que quedara vacío, y necesito evitar eso.
TinyMCE no me da ninguna opción para evitarlo, incluso en su demo permite enviar el textarea vacío.
He visto muchas webs donde han resuelto el hecho de que ha veces enviaba un párrafo vacío al final de cada texto (<p>&nbsp;</p>) y lo han resuelto con una nueva opción de configuración, pero no he visto que alguien haya tenido justo este problema que tengo, igual no se si es posible hacer algo con JS antes de que TinyMCE procese el formulario, claro, sin que el script tenga un comportamiento no deseado.
Intenté con
function verificar() {
    if ( $("#content").val().trim().length > 0 ) {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#content',
        height: 500,
        menubar: true,
        plugins: 'link lists',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | fontfamily fontsize formatselect | ' +
        ' link | bold italic underline forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
        'alignright alignjustify lineheight | checklist bullist numlist | indent outdent | ' +
        'removeformat',
        link_default_target: '_blank',
        link_assume_external_targets: 'https',
        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
    });
    }
    else{
        alert("El campo contiene espacios o está vacío");
    }
}

Pero el formulario se daña
Y con
function verificar() {
    if ( $("#content").val().trim().length > 0 ) {
        return '';
    }
    else{
        alert("El campo contiene espacios o está vacío");
    }
}

tinymce.init({
        selector: '#content',
        height: 500,... // resto de la config

No haca nada 
Alguna idea? 

Antes había intentado forzar el contenido e incluso reemplazarlo
$content = htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags(trim($_POST['content'])));
$content = str_replace("&nbsp;", '', $content);
echo $len = strlen($content); // 6

Ese resultado de 6 es con dos enter, y si le doy a ver código fuente no hay ni espacios, ni html ni nada, pero $content sigue teniendo un valor y por eso no entra al if de emty o incluso si pongo if (empty($content) OR $len = 0){ porque no se cumple, siempre la variable del contenido se queda con algo, que no es html, no es espacios...
He probado desde PHP con otras cosas y por eso quería ver si desde TinyMCE podía hacer algo...

Supongo que puedes hacer una combinacion de strip_tags, htmlspecialchars_decode y trim para ver lo que te queda después, y si es una cadena vacia pues ya lo tienes.

@masterguru ya lo había hecho. vea la actualización del post

Pues usa tambien $content = str_replace("\n", "", $content); para cargarte esos saltos de linea

Y también html_entity_decode() para cargarte los &nbsp; antes del trim

@masterguru el problema es que me quita el formato

A ver, no digo lo hagas para validar el formato, sino para detectar los casos de cadenas vacias pero llenas de etiquetas y espacios y saltos de línea, y que no quieres guardar de ese modo, sino en blanco.  Evidentemente, si tienen contenido no debes aplicar eso, simplemente lo permites guardar y ya está.  Pero si resulta que después de todas esas funciones la cadena está vacia pues la guardas vacia sin todo eso o haces lo que tengas que hacer, pero sabiéndolo.

He tenido estos problemas antes y los he resuelto del lado del servidor
La cosa es que solo empty no te va a ayudar mucho, combina trim con el empty al momento de evaluar
$content = strip_tags($_POST['content']); // Viene del POST

$content = str_replace("&nbsp;", '', $content);
$content = str_replace("<p></p>", '', $content);

/*echo $len = strlen($content).'<br>';
$foo = $content;
function is_empty($var){
    if (isset($var) === false  || $var === false  || $var === null  || $var === -0.0  || $var === ''  || $var === [])
    return true;
    return false;
}
echo is_empty($foo) ? "Empty<br>" :"Not Empty: $foo<br>";
var_dump(empty($content));*/

/* Acá es donde debes usar trim */
if (empty(trim($content))){
   ...

Todo lo comentado son controles para verificar la variable, te darás cuenta que los textos siempre tienen algún tipo de valor en ellos.
Pruébalo y me dices, en mi caso ha funcionado de esa manera. Pueda que tengas algo especial, pero si no es así te funcionará.
Te mando mi config general de TinyMCE por si quieres revisarla
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#content',
    height: 500,
    menubar: true,
    auto_focus: 'content',
    force_br_newlines : false,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    newline_behavior: 'block',
    newline_behavior: '',
    forced_root_block : '',
    plugins: 'link lists media table image',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | image | fontfamily fontsize formatselect | ' +
    ' link | bold italic underline forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
    'alignright alignjustify lineheight | checklist bullist numlist | indent outdent | ' +
    'removeformat',
    link_default_target: '_blank',
    link_assume_external_targets: 'https',
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
});


Yo que tu no me complicaría, por eso la solución a tu problema especifico viene enfocado a las herramientas de control, si esas que están comentadas en mi código PHP anterior.
Por ejemplo, el siguiente tiene una longitud de 200 caracteres exactos
        Hola



                      SOes



OCHOA



EOL

Al final, yo creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es limitar los caracteres de tu contenido a un numero especifico y con eso trabajar, sea lo que sea que hagas, si alguien quiere llenar de espacios o texto vacío ese contenido lo hará.
Yo usaría algo tan básico como
$content = $_POST['content'];
$length = strlen($content);

if ($length < '250'){ // O el número que quiras
   echo 'El contenido no puede tener menos de <b>250 caracteres</b>!!!';
   ...

Recuerda que el hecho de hacer lo siguiente en TinyMCE
Hola SOes Soy OCHOA ayudando a Yenn 
En la Base se convierten en más o menos 450 caracteres
<p><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 18pt;"><em><strong>Hola SOes Soy&nbsp;<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/61369/ochoa" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">OCHOA</span></a> ayudando a <span style="color: #000000; background-color: #f8cac6;">Yenn</span><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;</span></strong></em><strong><span style="color: #000000;"></span></strong></span></p>

Y considero que es una frase pequeña, pero todos los caracteres HTML agregados hacen que el número sea elevado, yo que tu pusiera unos 500 caracteres mínimo y fin a mis problemas...

Si, en efecto funciona pero el formato de TinyMCE se quita, pero al menos ya tengo resuelto el tema del texto en blanco

xD Hasta mucho tardaste en decir eso, es obvio que con eso matas todo el formato, deja que edite la respuesta...

En cualquiera de los casos tienes razón. Me iré por la ultima respuesta y poco a poco veremos como actúan los usuarios. Gracias
